# How can I create dynamic subdomains for dynamic domains

Tags: .htaccess

In the app I'm working at the moment, I need to dynamically create subdomains. That would be quite trivial if I knew what was the domain I need to redirect to.
The point is that I can have many domains pointing to the same server and each may have many subdomains and I want a htaccess that can handle it.

For example: domain1.com, domain1.com.br, domain2.com, domain2.co.uk can all be pointing to my server. When a user tries to access sub.domain1.com, I want it to be transparently redirected (no 301 redirect) to domain1.com. If he tries to access sub.domain1.com.br, I want it to be transparently redirected to domain1.com.br and so on (note that both redirects would point to the exact same point, the only difference would be in the address  bar).

By now, I tried unsuccessfully to make changes in the lines that redirect from www. to non-www domains, but nothing worked as expected:

```
    //This works
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    //This ends with a "too many redirections" error
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.([^.]{4,})\.([a-z]{3,4}|[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2.%3/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should cover all of these:

- domain1.com
- domain1.com.br
- domain2.co.uk
- domain3.es
- domain4.info

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem as it does a 301 redirect and I need that the redirect (don't even know if redirect is the proper name for it) happens transparently (without changing the url in the address bar).

Comment: @Robyflc Then change the `R=301` to `P`. Which means you're not redirecting (which means *change the URL in the browser's address bar*) but to internally proxy on the server, e.g. a **Reverse Proxy**).

Comment: I didn't know the P flag... Very interesting... Anyway, I didn't work either. The htaccess is now on meusite0800.com.br. If I try to access template.meusite0800.com.br (which was previously set up using cpanel and that I'm wishing to avoid), it still redirects to the main domain (even with the P flag). If I try a random subdomain which was not previously set up, it just gives me a page not found error.